# Python / PIL : How to gamma-blend images efficiently?

Tags: python, image, graphics, python-imaging-library

I'm looking for an efficient way to efficiently gamma-blend images.

While regular (additive) blend of pixels A and B with a factor r is expressed as this:

C = (1-r) A + r B

Gamma (multiplicative) blend is done as follows:

C = A^(1-r) B^r

This would require a way to raise a pixel channels to a non-integer power, a bit like a gamma correction.

Since I have a large batch of 4K images to process, I need this be done efficiently (without looping through all pixels and performing the computation individually).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating a function over the RGB values of individual pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800049/iterating-a-function-over-the-rgb-values-of-individual-pixels)

Comment: To do the computation efficiently, I think you'll need some other image processing or number crunching tool like NumPy -- not just PIL.

Comment: For example, [this does additive blending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3375291/190597), but it would not be hard to modify it to do multiplicative blending.

Comment: OK, I got the solution as follows: Convert the image as a numpy array, and perform whole-array mathematical operations, whatever needed...

Comment: @PascalMount Post this as the answer and accept it, it sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an implementation of the solution @Pascal Mount mentioned in the comments he used as he has yet to post his:

```py
import numpy as np

def blend_gamma_mul(img_A, img_B, r):
    arr_A = np.array(img_A)
    arr_B = np.array(img_B)
    arr_C = arr_A**(1-r) * arr_B**r
    return Image.fromarray(np.array(arr_C, dtype=np.uint8))
```

Use the function like so:

```py
from PIL import Image

img_A = Image.open("A.jpg")
img_B = Image.open("B.jpg")
img_C = blend_gamma_mul(img_A, img_B, 0.7)
img_C.save("C.jpg")
```

Took 3.47s on my computer to blend two 4k images.